# Decimal after two digit should contain 0 at second place should not be omitted

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am trying to round off value to two decimal places. but the issue is 0 at second is not appearing , it only shows decimal after one place.

i have fetched data from oracle db as 180.700 but while fetching it from db it shows only 180.7 in datatable after binding

```
 using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr_ipdmdm))
            {
                using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query))
                {
                    using (OracleDataAdapter sda = new OracleDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            sda.Fill(dt);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

while rounding it off to two decimal places it shows only one value after decimal i.e 180.7

```
Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(dt_spec.Rows[2]["YS"]), 2)
```

how can we show as 180.700 while binding it in datatable
and how can we round it two two decimal place i.e 180.70

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: If you don't need to work with it numerically in c# you can ask oracle to format it for you, or you can format it in c#. If you need to work with it numerically in c# get c# to format it

Comment: @Caius i am bringing data as it is from oracle , but while binding 0 after decimal removed eg 180.700 seen as 180.7 , iwant it like 180.700 further after binding will round it off  two 2 decimal but challenge is while binding . if you can suggest how to do.

Comment: Not 100% obvious what you mean by "binding" - different people mean different things by it. can you show the code that is doing your "binding"

Comment: @CaiusJard binding is already shown in code in the description

Comment: I can't see any, but I think your entire question is based on a misunderstanding. Oracle is storing 180.7, and maybe some query tool you have is showing it you as 180.700 because it;s a decimal(9,3), or because that;s what the tool is configured to do, and the value is coming to c# as 180.7 which is the same thing as 180.700 as 180.70. The datatable will store 180.7; if you want to see 180.70 in whateve rit is youre using to look a tthis data, then you have to have that thing format the number when it is displaying it. Numeric types don't have leading or trailing zeroes; that's a display only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get oracle to round and format it

```
TO_CHAR(numbercolumn, 'FM999990D00')
```

This converts to a string in oracle so your c# app will receive a string. If you need to work with it numerically in c# you could have oracle round it instead

```
ROUND(numbercol, 2)
```

But depending on what you're doing it may be best to leave the precise decimals on and do all your work with it then format it at the end of the work

```
calculatedResult.ToString("0.00")

$"{calculatedResult:0.00}"

string.Format("{0:0.00}", calculatedResult)
```

You don't need to Math.Round it first. Formatting 1.2355 as "0.00" becomes "1.24"

---

If you're using this datatable of yours in something like a windows forms DataGridView then it's the job of the grid to format the data, not on you to change it to a string. Look at something like

```
TheDgv.Columns[TheColumnIndex].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0.00";
```

And make sure the data in the datatable column is numeric, not a string

Answer (score 0):

Preface: I know nothing about C#. I do have a logic suggestion though! Consider interpreting/casting the number as a string/chararray, and concatenating a bunch of zeros to the end of the string. Then, cast back to floating point, and do the roundoff. There should be another zero there.

I'm not very familiar with the functions being used, but this logic has worked in the past in other languages.